# What is the maximum size of an micro SD card for Raspberry Pi Zero?

Tags: sd-card, pi-zero

Like the question says...  I can't seem to find any definitive information anywhere.

Comment: I don't see how this is a dup.  I am asking a Pi Zero specific question, not regarding the regular Pi.

Comment: Pi Zero uses the same processor like the B+ and would have the same specs for the SD card. 

In general, It is recommended to use SDHC cards which come upto 32GB. People have also used SDXC cards upto 512GB and there is no reason why they wont work at all. You should be a bit cautious when choosing the SD card because there are a lot of SD cards which don;t work well with the Pi. 

Here is the definitive list of SD cards which work and don;t work with the Pi http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards